# ReactJS automatically simulate keyboard

Tags: reactjs, input, keyboard, frontend, simulate

some one help me please, in the codesandbox link here [codesandboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-automatically-simulate-keyboard-zzrdi?file=/demo.js) you can see 2 input type of text, i want in the second input, when you focus and press key "backspace" the cursor pointer will automatically focus on the first input, thank for helping me out, hope you have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to listen to the `onKeyDown` event. When the event fires, it passes the `KeyboardEvent` argument that you can use to inspect what key is pressed and other relevant infos. In this case you will need to look for the `KeyboardEvent.keyCode`. Logging the keycode when you type will reveal the keyCode of the key you just pressed.

```
<input
  type="text"
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
    console.log('pressing', e.keyCode)
    }
  }}
/>
```

After that, you need get the reference of the `input` to be able to focus the input conditionally.

```
export default function Demo() {
  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    const BACKSPACE_KEY = 8;
    const ENTER_KEY = 13;
    const form = e.target.form;
    const index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(form, e.target);

    let el;
    if (e.keyCode === ENTER_KEY) {
      el = form.elements[index + 1];
    } else if (e.keyCode === BACKSPACE_KEY) {
      el = form.elements[index - 1];
    }
    if (el) el.focus();

    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />
      <input type="text" onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />
      <input type="text" onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />
      <input type="text" onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />
      <input type="text" onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit react-automatically-simulate-keyboard (forked)]

Comment: thank you, it work perfectly with what i have expected, but what happen when i have more than 2, i mean it can be 20 or 30 inputs because i have been doing an text editor, so i can not make ref for each of them manually, thank you so much

Comment: You don't need to write any code to do that. Simply press `Tab` to focus the next input and `Shift`+`Tab` to focus the previous input

Comment: but i can not find the method to automatically press tab or shift+tab, the requirement does not accept do it manually

Comment: @TamDo I just updated my code and the live example. It should work fine now.

Comment: thank you so much, i had a look at it, it will be a perfect example for me to continue my project